# repositoryPath does not work when custom packages folder in nuget.config

Tags: package, nuget

I have a `nuget.config` file in root folder of my solution, I want to use `repositoryPath`, instead of `globalPackagesFolder`, as `globalPackagesFolder` downloads a very long list of packages to folder, but `repositoryPath` does not work instead, which really confused me.

```xml
<config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="./packages1" />
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="./packages2" />
</config>
```

I will only keep 1 line for `packages` folder. everytime when I made changes to nuget.config, I've run `git clean -xdf` and also restart Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible.

Which folder is used is a function of the project style.

From the [managing the global packages and cache folders doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders).

> The `global-packages` folder is where NuGet installs any downloaded package. Each package is fully expanded into a subfolder that matches the package identifier and version number. Projects using the PackageReference format always use packages directly from this folder. When using the packages.config, packages are installed to the global-packages folder, then copied into the project's packages folder.

The global packages folder can be shared across projects, solutions and even a whole machine.

If you have PackageReference projects, you have no choice but to use the `globalPackagesFolder`. Note that you can't have them point to the same location, because as you have observed, they have a different structure.